# How to set the additional attribute in a WHMCS addon module

Tags: php, api, whmcs

I am using a addon/Hook on WHMCS called Transaction Email Notification 1.4

```
<?php
// Transaction Email Notification 1.4 (25-Oct-2016)

function sendEmailTemplateForTransaction($vars)
{
    global $_LANG;

    // create email if not created
    $emailTemplateName = $_LANG['notifyWhenTransactionTemplate'];
    
    // get firstname and lastname of user
    $command = "getclientsdetails";
    $adminuser = xxxxxx; // set WHMCS admin user
    $values["clientid"] = $vars['userid'];
    $resultsStats = localAPI($command, $values, $adminuser);
    $userFirstLastName = $resultsStats['firstname'] . ' ' . $resultsStats['lastname'];

    $emailTemplateName = $_LANG['notifyWhenTransactionTemplate'];

    // send information to email template
    $command = "sendadminemail";
    $values["messagename"] = $emailTemplateName;
    $values["mergefields"] = array(
            "userid" => $vars['userid'],
            "currencyid" => $vars['currencyid'],
            "gateway" => $vars['gateway'],
            "date" => $vars['date'],
            "description" => $vars['description'],
            "amountin" => $vars['amountin'],
            "fees" => $vars['fees'],
            "amountout" => $vars['amountout'],
            "rate" => $vars['rate'],
            "transid" => $vars['transid'],
            "invoiceid" => $vars['invoiceid'],
            "refundid" => $vars['refundid'],
            "id" => $vars['id'],
            "clientname" => $userFirstLastName,
    );

    $results = localAPI($command, $values, $adminuser);

}

add_hook("AddTransaction", 1, "sendEmailTemplateForTransaction");
```

i would like to have also the Invoice Item be shown on the send transaction emails.

So i add some line:

```
        // get Invoice Details
    $command = "getinvoice";
    $adminuser = xxxxx // set WHMCS admin user
    $values["invoiceid"] = $vars['invoiceid'];
    $resultsStats = localAPI($command, $values, $adminuser);
    $desc = $resultsStats['items']["item"][0]["description"];
```

and

```
"desc" => $desc,
```

it works fine, but display only the first line of the Invoice in the Email, but i need the complete Invoice Items to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `$resultsStats['items']["item"]` is an array of items, so you can iterate through it to get all descriptions:

```php
$desc = '';
foreach ($resultsStats['items']["item"] as $item) {
$desc.=$item["description"]."\r\n"; // "\r\n" is line break; replace it per your needs
}
```

Comment: Also it could be that `$resultsStats['items']` is array of items, so you would have to alter the code a bit in order for it to work properly. Look in your debugger (or simply `var_dump($resultsStats['items']);` to see the array format where actual items are stored.

Comment: i have tried it..it shows now all item..but not with a line break..:(

Comment: Like I mentioned, you can replace line break to something that fits your needs. If you're outputting the data as HTML, replace `"\r\n"` with `"<br>"`

Comment: Sorry, your examples aren't displaying properly. Can you make a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: how can i here in the comment add something in a new line??

i think wo dont speak from the same
i dont have any idea how to replace the "\r\n"

Comment: https://ibb.co/6J2T2ft

left side: the Email......right side the invoice items as shown in original

Comment: Replace this line `$desc.=$item["description"]."\r\n";` with this `$desc.=$item["description"]."<br>";`

Comment: no dont work..not it display the <br> :-)

https://ibb.co/jRSLRhw

..... maybe WHMCS need a an another as "\r\n" for Line Break Syntax

Comment: I see, HTML tags are escaped. You need to have a look at your email template file and see how it outputs the data. Then you can alter it to either allow HTML tags (might be not a good idea) or consider line breaks in some other way.

Comment: the problem is. that in example, the template for the Invoice Payment Confirmation (which shows also the item) use an another variable    ..... .{$invoice_html_contents} .....

but i dont find the solution to add {$invoice_html_contents} and use this instead of ......$desc = $resultsStats['items']["item"][0]["description"];

Comment: Try to change `{$invoice_html_contents}` to `{$invoice_html_contents|nl2br}` and replace `"\r\n"` to `"\n"` in the code from my answer.

Comment: {$invoice_html_contents}  is impossible to use on the hook,.thats my problem...only the line i writte here in my first post, works :(

Comment: You need to edit your email template as I mentioned above.

Comment: the Email template has only this Service: {$desc}   to get the informations from the api

ok with {$desc|nl2br}  it looks a little bit better :) Thank you!

Comment: Then try `{$desc|nl2br}}`